# Еще раз про перегрузку операторов для своего класса строк

Tags: c++, строки, перегрузка-операторов

Задача написать свой класс "Строка". Столкнулся с такой проблемой: во время выполнения программы ошибка "`Expression:CrtlsValidHeapPointer(block)`".

Предполагаю, ошибка где-то в конструкторах или присваивании, но разобраться не могу.

```
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>

class my_string
{
private:
    int length;
    char *symbols;
public:
    my_string()
    {
        length = 0;
        symbols = new char[100];
    }
    ~my_string()
    {
        delete symbols;
    }
    my_string(const my_string& s)
    {
        length = s.length;
        symbols = new char(*s.symbols);
    }
    my_string my_string::operator=(const my_string& s)
    {
        length = s.length;
        symbols = new char(*s.symbols);
        return *this;
    }
    my_string my_string::operator+=(const my_string& s)
    {
        my_string tmp;
        delete tmp.symbols;
        length = strlen(symbols) + strlen(s.symbols);
        tmp.symbols = new char[length + 1];
        strcpy(tmp.symbols, symbols);
        strcat(tmp.symbols, s.symbols);
        delete symbols;
        symbols = new char[length + 1];
        strcpy(symbols, tmp.symbols);
        delete tmp.symbols;
        return *this;
    }
    bool my_string::operator==(const my_string& s)
    {
        if (strcmp(symbols, s.symbols))
            return false;
        else return true;
    }
    my_string clean_string()
    {
        delete symbols;
        my_string();
        return *this;
    }
};
```

Данные в `symbols` ввожу с помощью `std::cin>>symbols`, но убрал, чтобы не захламлять код

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Все случаи, когда делается

   ```
   symbols = new char(*s.symbols);
   ```

   это какая-то бессмыслица. Это выделение памяти для *одного символа* строки и копирование *одного символа*. Разумеется, одного символа совершенно недостаточно для хранения строки ненулевой длины.

   При этом в реализации оператора `+=` такой бессмыслицы не наблюдается - там память выделяется более-менее правильно. Почему наблюдается такая разница?
2. Освобождение памяти, выделенной через `new[]`, делается через `delete[]`, а не через `delete`.
3. В операторе `+=` тем не менее написана масса ерунды. Например, в конце делается `delete tmp.symbols;`, после чего будет автоматически вызван деструктор `tmp`, который снова сделает `delete tmp.symbols;`. Все накроется.
4. Оператор присваивания должен освобождать старое содержимое объекта, а затем копировать в него новое. Я не вижу у вас освобождения старого содержимого. У вас вообще оператор присваивания совпадает с конструктором копирования, что бессмысленно.
5. Что вы хотели сказать вот этим

   ```
   my_string();
   ```

   внутри `clean_string`? И зачем `clean_string` возвращает какую-то строку по значению?
6. Еще масса мелких странностей и ошибок.

Comment: Большое спасибо, буду исправлять